# what does "practice" mean in this contex?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> One criticism of Piaget's theory is that culture and education exert
>   stronger influences on a child's development than Piaget maintained.
>   These factors depend on how much **practice** their culture provides in
>   developmental processes, such as conversational skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/practice, definition #2. Do something repeatedly to learn or enhance one's skill. The writer is saying that in some cultures, children get a lot of practice in conversation, that is, they frequently talk to other people so they learn to speak well, while in other cultures they don't.